# Secure GoDaddy site with Azure SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, godaddy, azure-web-apps

Appologies in advanced, IT is REALLY not my strong suit so bear with me

### Setup

1) I have a godaddy domain with linux hosting that I use for a landing page, let's say `www.mywebsite.com`

2) I have an azure web app that I configed using a CNAME record and is accessible at `app.mywebsite.com`.

3) I have a wildcard SSL certificate on Azure that is configured with SSL bindings for `app.mywebsite.com`.

this works well and I am able to browse to `app.mywebsite.com` via HTTPS.

### Question

Can I use the same certificate to secure my landing page at `www.mywebsite.com`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a certificate for `*.mywebsite.com`, then you can use it on both `app.mywebsite.com` and `www.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: thanks .. I see that but I'm unclear about how I go about using the AZURE created SSL to secure the landing page hosted outside of AZURE on godaddy linux hosting